# htaccess url-rewrite specific file to subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've been searching for hours now hoping to find a solution for my problem. But all I find is something like an URL-rewrite from folder to folder. Nothing related to my question.

Well I'm trying to achieve an URL-rewrite from a script (e.g. `confirm.php`) to a script in a subfolder (e.g. `scripts/confirm.php`).

Something like this

```
www.example.com/confirm.php?id=somevalue&key=somevalue
```

to

```
www.example.com/scripts/confirm.php?id=somevalue&key=somevalue
```

where the values of the parameters are variable and the page can be visited via http/https and with or without www.

Comment: "Redirect" or "URL-Rewrite"? You mention "Redirect" throughout your question, but you've also tagged your question "url-rewriting" and used "rewrite" in the title? Please clarify.

Comment: @w3dk thanks, I have edited my question. As the title said I'm looking for an URL-rewrite solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below rule, in your root directory, I am assuming confirm.php is not exist in root directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^confirm\.php$ scripts/confirm.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: What? is there some other rule working? please provide your current .htaccess.

Comment: You were faster with answering than me with deleting my comment. Yes, you're right. I had another rule overwriting this one. It works now, thank you so much!